# Win x32 project on a Win x64 IDE and Java

Tags: java, version

What are the challenges of importing a project created on eclipse x32 with Java x32 to eclipse x64 with java x64?

Comment: I think you mean x86 which is 32-bit. There is no x32.

Comment: yes thanks, repeated the same mistake

Answer (score 3):

Java is cross platform so you should not have any problems.

That being said, if you are using native libraries that require 32 bit, then you will not be able to run the project in a 64 bit JVM. Similarly, 64 bit native libraries will not work in a 32 bit JVM.

Eclipse is indifferent to what architecture you are targeting with your project. Even if your project requires a 32 bit JVM in order to run, you can still develop it in a 32 or a 64 bit running instance of Eclipse. You will be able to compile and package ('export') projects regardless of machine architecture. For running the project within Eclipse you will have to specify a 32 bit JVM or otherwise the native libraries will fail to load.

Comment: In our case we have eclipse RCP so i would imagine its x86 libraries will fail on RCP x64

Comment: Sounds like it. RCP should be using SWT native libraries, which definitely are supported on both 32 and 64 bit. The SWT java binaries may actually bootstrap the proper SWT native libraries for you. Give it a shot.